# How to calculate take home salary in Sacramento, California?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, calculation, salary, california

How can I calculate my take home pay in Sacramento area in California?

I have an offer of USD 95,000 per year in Sacramento. After searching multiple sites for tax calculations, I understood that it depends on the number of dependents as well.

I have a spouse not working, and one child of 4 years.

Can someone please suggest, how much take home pay I can expect?

Comment: You will also need to know how much insurance costs or any other optional deductions.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes, my question also seems to be same. But I would like to know if I can get some rough estimate through any reliable site.

Comment: Looking for asite recommendation makes this a "shopping question", whis is generally out of scope because best answers change frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go here:

[Paycheck calculator](http://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/salary/)

This will help you calculate your take home pay given different scenarios.  Keep in mind that this does not accurately calculate your tax liability.